# Is it possible to intercept Vue Router push and other actions?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am hoping to create some middle ware whenever Vue router is used for example if someone where to do `this.$router.push({//insertReq})`.

I would like to read the details of what is in the push and either redirect their push or allow it for all Router requests across all components in the website.

Comment: So, you are looking for [`beforeEach`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards)?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Hero, thanks completely forgot about that.